# cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field SlackServiceProperties.properties.notify_only_broken_pipelines of type bool

Tags: go, gitlab, terraform

I have the following terraform config to to setup slack integration with gitlab

```
resource "gitlab_service_slack" "this" {
  project = gitlab_project.this.id
  webhook = module.defaults.slack_webhook_url

  username                     = "GitLab"
  branches_to_be_notified      = "protected"
  pipeline_events              = true
  notify_only_broken_pipelines = true
  count = var.slack_enabled ? 1 : 0
}
```

When I `terrafrom plan` this I recieve this error:

**Error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field SlackServiceProperties.properties.notify_only_broken_pipelines of type bool**

It looks valid to me according to [this page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/service_slack#notify_only_broken_pipelines).

Here is the version info

```
Terraform v0.12.29
+ provider.gitlab v2.11.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.tls v2.2.0
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like it may have been fixed: https://github.com/gitlabhq/terraform-provider-gitlab/issues/348

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in the terraform gitlab provider that has been fixed. See https://github.com/gitlabhq/terraform-provider-gitlab/issues/348